# How to search the words using key in jquery quickselect js?

Tags: jquery, quickselect.js

Hai am using jquery quickselect js for searching from [quickselect](https://github.com/dcparker/jquery_plugins/tree/master/quickselect/)  its working fine,but know i need to add the keyword searching.**For example** i have a keywords for apple is "Healthyfruit". when i typed healthyfruit the apple will come....i want to show like that.How to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link [jQueryUI Autocomplete - how to match search words with a list of keywords and show the matched results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040137/jqueryui-autocomplete-how-to-match-search-words-with-a-list-of-keywords-and-sh/9043814#9043814).This may help you.This is jquery autocomplete search.