# How to search keywords in Autocomplete (jQuery ui)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to load an xml file and activate Autocomplete (jQuery UI) for showing data from the xml into the input box, while a user starts typing in the input field.

Currently, My script uses `source: data,` where data is the loaded xml arrays via .map function jquery. The user input is being searched via the `value` field of the xml, but I now need to make it search via the `keywords` field. That's because the keywords are more valid in my requirement where a single value can hold two or three keywords.

I searched on google and stackoverflow whole evening and uptil midnight yesterday for this, and found a page on [ [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040137/jqueryui-autocomplete-how-to-match-search-words-with-a-list-of-keywords-and-sh) ] , and tried to use the code given on that page.

The code runs almost fine, but I cannot view the some of the elements, in the autocomplete. The data is loading fine, and shows correct value for any called index of the data array: `(console.log(data[1].value);` = `sparrow` in chrome's console. (as per my xml)

but after the search function: `checkSearchWordsMatchKeywords(request.term, keywords))`, the value of [k] is changed, and it only returns some of the results, not all.

First I thought that it's not returning the first element, so I copied it and pasted it to the start to make a copy of it as [0]..for testing purpose. but that didn't seem to function either, so I guess it's not showing that particular set of keywords.

I don't intend to use this script as it is, ... instead I'm posting here for an info on how I can search KEYWORDS in autocomplete. If this function is not correct, then please could someone provide a different function, or suggest a different autocomplete script/plugin for this purpose? I intend to only use jQuery for this.

The following code only returns "Parrot", "Crow", "Pidgeon", but doesn't return "Sparrow" when I type "t" in the input field. As per the keywords, it should also return "Sparrow", but it doesn't.

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <item>
        <id>0</id>
        <value>NoValue</value>
        <url>#noValue</url>
        <keywords>ewo;reeFour;veSix</keywords>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <value>Sparrow</value>
        <url>gallery/birds_1.html</url>
        <keywords>OneTwo;ThreeFour;FiveSix</keywords>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <value>Parrot</value>
        <url>gallery/birds_2.html</url>
        <keywords>SevenEigh;Nineen;tElevenwelve</keywords>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <value>Crow</value>
        <url>gallery/birds_3.html</url>
        <keywords>ThirteenFourteen;FifteenSixteen;SeventeenEighteen</keywords>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>4</id>
        <value>Dove</value>
        <url>gallery/Birds_4.html</url>
        <keywords>Nineeenweny;wenyOnewenywo;wenyhreewenyFour</keywords>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>5</id>
        <value>Pidgeon</value>
        <url>gallery/birds_5.html</url>
        <keywords>TwentyFiveTwentySix;TwentySevenTwentyEight;TwentyNineThirty</keywords>
    </item>
</items>
```

## Javascript:

```
        /* get xml file using ajax */
$.ajax({
    url: "birds_search.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xmlResponse) {
         /* parse response */
         var data = $("item", xmlResponse).map(function() {
         return {
             id: $("id", this).text(),
             value: $("value", this).text(),
             url: $("url", this).text(), 
             comma_keywords: $("keywords", this).text(), 
             //can add "../" to the url via label tag: label: "../" + url; ... and then in SELECT below, : ui.item.label. (for products directory.xml)
         };
         }).get();
        console.log(data[1].value);

         /* bind the results to autocomplete */
         $("input#autocomplete_search").autocomplete({
             source: function(request, response) {        
                        var matched = [];
                        var k;
                        // Search "request.term" through all links keywords
                        for (k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
                        var keywords = data[k].comma_keywords.split(';');
                            //console.log(k);
                            if (checkSearchWordsMatchKeywords(request.term, keywords)) {
                                matched.push(data[k]);
                                console.log(k);
                            }
                        }
                        // display the filtered results
                        response(matched);
                    },
             //minLength: 2,
             select: function (event, ui) {
            window.location = ui.item.url;
            }
         });




     }
});




function checkSearchWordsMatchKeywords(searchString, keywords)
{
    var searchWords = searchString.toLowerCase().split(' ');    // Lowercase the search words & break up the search into separate words
    var numOfSearchWords = searchWords.length;                  // Count number of search words
    var numOfKeywords = keywords.length;                        // Count the number of keywords
    var matches = [];                                           // Will contain the keywords that matched the search words

    // For each search word look up the keywords array to see if the search word partially matches the keyword
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfSearchWords; i++)
    {
        // For each keyword
        for (var j = 0; j < numOfKeywords; j++)
        {   
            // Check search word is part of a keyword
            if (keywords[j].indexOf(searchWords[i]) != -1)
            {
                // Found match, store match, then look for next search word
                matches.push(keywords[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Count the number of matches, and if it equals the number of search words then the search words match the keywords
    if (matches.length == numOfSearchWords)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm answering my own question quite late... but this is how I finally managed to achieve it. I'm only copy/pasting the code here as it is in my js file, so that no error occurs. In my Question, I had given an example of `birds.xml`, which is now in my case, `products.xml` ...

`fileStatus` variable is true or false depending on the location of the xml file.... which I've set during an ajax request to check for the file (not included in this code)... you can change that as per your wish, as it's optional. Rest of the code should be fine for the autocomplete.... or you can just change whatever bits of code doesn't match your requirement. :D

```
$("input#q").autocomplete({
             source: function products(request, response) {   // Function PRODUCTS() 
                        function hasMatch(s) {
                        //console.log(s);
                        //console.log(request.term.toLowerCase());
                        return s.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase())!==-1;
                    }
                    var i, l, obj, matches = [];
                    //console.log(data_global);
                    if (request.term==="") {
                        response([]);
                        return;
                    }
                    for  (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    obj = data[i];
                    //var truefalseVar;
                    //console.log(obj.value);
                    function truefalse(){
                    for(j=0;j<obj.gen_name.length;j++)
                    { if( hasMatch(obj.gen_name[j]) )
                        return true;
                        //else truefalseVar = false;
                    //  console.log(obj.gen_name[j])
                    }
                    return false;
                    }
                    if (hasMatch(obj.value) || truefalse() ) {
                        matches.push(obj);
                        }
                    }
                response(matches);
                },
            /* END OF  Function PRODUCTS() */
             //minLength: 2,

             focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $(event.target).val(ui.item.gen_name);
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                },

             select: function (event, ui) {
             if(fileStatus){
             var prouctsURL = 'products/' + ui.item.url;
             }
             else var prouctsURL = ui.item.url;
            window.location = prouctsURL;
            }
         });
```